# cannot select vertices in blender

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices, blend-files, select

I cannot do anything when I get into edit mode. Can't select anything. even when pressing a i cant move it. but I still can select the other vertex in the other vertex.  here is a link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MiR1jhHOYzQZ-N9mbtlaEPJVVHYNlA3S/view?usp=sharing

btw tell me if you cant access the file. I've never done this before

Edit: It only happens when you go to sculpting workspace and back while selecting the head object i made

Comment: hello, you are in Sculpt mode, if I switch to Edit mode I can select anything I want. You can't select vertices in Sculpt mode (at least not that I know)

Comment: yes, but when you come back from sculpt mode you cant select anything anymore

Comment: it works here so it must be a bug, maybe try Alt H?

Comment: thanks now it works but why cant i sculpt

Comment: when you press Alt H in Edit mode then switch back to Sculpt mode you can't sculpt anymore?